# Naming a column as a parameter passed in to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameterized-query

I have a stored procedure that takes in a parameter @n and @colname and uses @n to compute some information. Right now @colname does nothing because T-SQL does not allow you to make a column name from a parameter. There are examples of people saying you can do this through a dynamic stored procedure, but as far as I can tell, they do not do what I want.

The reason behind this is because I want to create another stored procedure that uses this other stored procedure several times and passes different values of @n and @colname.

So just to clarify again, I would like to be able to write a dynamic stored procedure that does this:

```
SELECT a, b, c AS @colname
FROM t1
WHERE b = @n
```

Then once I can do that, I will write my other stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC stored_procedure1 @n = 3, @colname = 'Column 1'
EXEC stored_procedure1 @n = 6, @colname = 'Column 2'
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only parameterize data. you can't parameterize column names, table names, or aliases. It's only possible if you use dynamic sql, but that is something I would only go to as a last resort. Why do you need different aliases for the column in the first place?

Comment: I want to use dynamic sql, I'm not worried about sql injection or anything like that. I need different aliases because each column will represent different data. The actual queries are much more complex than what I wrote above, I just wanted to give a simple example

Comment: That looks fragile and get-out.

Comment: You should ALWAYS write your t-sql so it isn't vulnerable to sql injection. Saying you aren't worried is a bad approach.

Comment: @Sean, I tried for lots of time to not have to use a dynamic query, but after many hours of failing I am not sure it is possible so I am going with dynamic for now. Thanks for the concern though

Comment: Dynamic sql does NOT mean you can't prevent sql injection.

Comment: Got it, well I'll worry about the sql injecetion once I can get the query working. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it a dynamic query like below

```
EXEC ('SELECT a, b, c AS ['+ @colname +
'] FROM t1 WHERE b = ' + @n)
```

Hope rest you can figure out.

Comment: you are missing a space between the alias and the from. also, I would use square brackets around the alias to enable aliases with white spaces or that are reserved words and such.

Comment: This works until there is a space in @colname. Then this is broken. It should be wrapped in QUOTENAME.

Comment: Fortunately all of my columns will be without spaces but thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @SeanLange, good points. Edited answer to include that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing this using the fine example posted by Rahul. This will accommodate a space and will prevent sql injection. Please notice that the where predicate has been parameterized too.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = 'SELECT a, b, c AS ' + quotename(@colname) + 
' FROM t1 WHERE b = @n'

exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@n int', @n = @n
```